# Calling a method (that mutates state) from two different useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am playing around with React Hooks, calling a method (that mutates state) from two different useEffect. Following code is given:

```
function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  /**
   * Listen for clicked changes. When clicked changes to true,
   * allow setCounterAndSetUrlHash to do it's thing, before accpeting
   * the next click. So the clicked flag is simply a valve, that opens
   * after two seconds.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicked) {
      setCounterAndSetUrlHash(counter + 1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setClicked(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [clicked]);

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  /**
   * Listen for changes in the URL hash. When the user presses
   * the back button in the browser toolbar, decrement the
   * counter value.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onhashchange = () => {
      const value = Number(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));
      // must be number
      if (typeof value === "number" && value % 1 === 0) {
        if (counter - 1 === value) {
          setCounterAndSetUrlHash(counter - 1);
        }
      }
    };
  });

  /**
   * Set a new counter value and apply the same value
   * to the URL hash. I want to reuse this function
   * in both useEffect above.
   */
  const setCounterAndSetUrlHash = value => {
    setCounter(value);
    if (value === 0) {
      window.location.hash = "";
    } else {
      window.location.hash = String(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Clicked: {String(clicked)}</p>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shadow-7xesm

The code is actually working. However I am getting this warning..

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'counter'. Either
>   include it or remove the dependency array.
>   (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

.. and I am not sure how to conform with that while keeping the current functionality. When I add counter to the dependencies, I end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first effect uses `counter` state variable but its dependency list does not include it. Including it in dependency list will create infinite loop.

You can remove the dependency on `counter` by using function type argument in `setCounter`.

```
function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  /**
   * Listen for clicked changes. When clicked changes to true,
   * allow setCounterAndSetUrlHash to do it's thing, before accpeting
   * the next click. So the clicked flag is simply a valve, that opens
   * after two seconds.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicked) {
      incrCounter(1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setClicked(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [clicked]);

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  /**
   * Listen for changes in the URL hash. When the user presses
   * the back button in the browser toolbar, decrement the
   * counter value.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onhashchange = () => {
      const value = Number(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));
      // must be number
      if (typeof value === "number" && value % 1 === 0) {
        if (counter - 1 === value) {
          incrCounter(- 1);
        }
      }
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      window.location.hash = "";
    } else {
      window.location.hash = String(counter);
    }
  }, [counter])
  /**
   * Set a new counter value and apply the same value
   * to the URL hash. I want to reuse this function
   * in both useEffect above.
   */
  const incrCounter = delta => {
    setCounter(value => value + delta);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Clicked: {String(clicked)}</p>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the functional setState, [`setState((state, props) => stateChange)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (clicked) {
    setCounterAndSetUrlHash(counter => counter + 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClicked(false);
    }, 2000);
  }
}, [clicked]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of the `onhashchange` callback using the first counter value I suggest to move the functionality to the callback of `setCounter`. This would also imply that you need a different function for the button and the hash change.

Also set the variables and `useState` definitions at the top, and after `useEffect` which can make use of them. If you want a `useEffect` to run only once, set an empty array of dependencies; leaving out dependecies will run on every render.

```
export const App = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    /**
     * Listen for clicked changes. When clicked changes to true,
     * allow setCounterAndSetUrlHash to do it's thing, before accpeting
     * the next click. So the clicked flag is simply a valve, that opens
     * after two seconds.
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        if (clicked) {
            setCounter(counter => {
                const value = counter + 1;

                if (value === 0) {
                    window.location.hash = "";
                } else {
                    window.location.hash = String(value);
                }

                return value;
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
                setClicked(false);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }, [clicked]);

    /**
     * Listen for changes in the URL hash. When the user presses
     * the back button in the browser toolbar, decrement the
     * counter value.
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        window.onhashchange = e => {
            const value = Number(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));

            // must be number
            if (typeof value === "number" && value % 1 === 0) {
                setCounter(counter => {

                    if (counter - 1 !== value) {
                        return counter;
                    }

                    if (value === 0) {
                        window.location.hash = "";
                    } else {
                        window.location.hash = String(value);
                    }

                    return value;
                });
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>Clicked: {String(clicked)}</p>
            <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add counter to the first useEffect():

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clicked) {
      setCounterAndSetUrlHash(counter + 1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setClicked(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, [clicked, counter]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sun-56u7j